# Deferred: Connection timed out

Tags: debian, sendmail

I am installing Sendmail on a Debian box. I have tried twice now and each time am getting the connection deferred error. I have run the following processes:

```
apt-get purge sendmail*
apt update
apt install sendmail sendmail-cf m4
sendmailconfig (I answered Y to all)
sendmail -vt < ~/mail.txt (FAILED)
nano /etc/mail/local-host-names (added web1 and web1.mydomain.com)
m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
service sendmail restart
sendmail -vt < ~/mail.txt
```

The contents of hostnamectl:

```
root@web1:~# hostnamectl
   Static hostname: web1.mydomain.com
     Icon name: computer-vm
       Chassis: vm
    Machine ID: bf9dd17320f042e1b8715468578181b6
       Boot ID: 8981063e23dd4c07905ea630f2ab0a75
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
        Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-9-amd64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

And the contents of /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost web1.mydomain.com
213.168.250.175 web1
```

My message is accepted by Sendmail for sending but never completes. Normally this problem can be errors with telneting port 25 but I have tested for that and was successful.

Here is the results when I run the sendmail command:

```
root@web1:~# sendmail -vt < ~/mail.txt
test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 web1.mydomain.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1; Wed, 1 Jul 2020 18:08:16 +0100; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO web1.mydomain.com
250-web1.mydomain.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<surveymechanics@web1.mydomain.com> SIZE=156 AUTH=surveymechanics@web1.mydomain.com
250 2.1.0 <surveymechanics@web1.mydomain.com>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
050 <test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com>... Connecting to reception.mail-tester.com. via esmtp...
050 <test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com>... Deferred: Connection timed out with reception.mail-tester.com.
250 2.0.0 061H8GYO004063 Message accepted for delivery
test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com... Sent (061H8GYO004063 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 web1.mydomain.com closing connection
root@web1:~# sendmail -vt < ~/mail.txt -i -t
test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 web1.mydomain.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1; Wed, 1 Jul 2020 18:09:32 +0100; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO web1.mydomain.com
250-web1.mydomain.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<surveymechanics@web1.mydomain.com> SIZE=156 AUTH=surveymechanics@web1.mydomain.com
250 2.1.0 <surveymechanics@web1.mydomain.com>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
050 <test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com>... Connecting to reception.mail-tester.com. via esmtp...
050 <test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com>... Deferred: Connection timed out with reception.mail-tester.com.
250 2.0.0 061H9Wwn004147 Message accepted for delivery
test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com... Sent (061H9Wwn004147 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 web1.mydomain.com closing connection
```

**Why would I be getting a connection deferred?** I just cannot see what else could be causing the problem.

Results with extra debugging:

```
root@web1:~# sendmail -vt < ~/mail.txt -i -t -d8.20 -d60.5 -Am -i
_res.options = 52c3, HasWildcardMX = 0
map_lookup(dequote, mydomain, %0=mydomain) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(host, srv1.mail-tester.com, %0=srv1.mail-tester.com) => dns_getcanonname(srv1.mail-tester.com, trymx=1)
dns_getcanonname: trying srv1.mail-tester.com. (AAAA)
    NO: errno=0, h_errno=4
dns_getcanonname: trying srv1.mail-tester.com. (A)
    NO: errno=0, h_errno=4
dns_getcanonname: trying srv1.mail-tester.com. (MX)
    YES
dns_getcanonname: srv1.mail-tester.com
srv1.mail-tester.com. (0)
getmxrr(srv1.mail-tester.com., droplocalhost=1)
test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com... Connecting to reception.mail-tester.com. via esmtp...
test-60gvg4qzb@srv1.mail-tester.com... Deferred: Connection timed out with reception.mail-tester.com.
```

Comment: Question updated. thanks

Comment: Are you **SURE** your outgoing SMTP connections are not firewalled out? e.g. by your ISP as outgoing-spam prevention method.  Do you get SMTP greeting message? `telnet reception.mail-tester.com. 25`

Comment: Updated answer with debug info

Comment: telnet gives me `telnet reception.mail-tester.com. 25 Trying 94.23.206.89...`

Comment: You should have a chat with your hosting provider.

Comment: Deferred means that the Sendmail server cannot connect to the recipient server and it's putting the email on hold until later when it retries. The reasons for not being able to connect to the recipient server could be: 1. Server is down 2. Your box is blocked from connecting to external systems on port 25. 3. Intermittent network badness.